# Requirement for __init__.py just to satisfy pylint and mypy

Tags: python, pylint, mypy

I have a project with the following (partial) directory structure

```
.
├── mypy.ini
├── src
│   ├── preppy
│   │   ├── cli.py
│   │   ├── __main__.py
│   │   ├── model.py
│   │   └── tools.py
├── pyproject.toml
└── tests
```

In `cli.py`, I have the following code (lines 13 and 14 in the file):

```
from .model import Problem
from .tools import get_abs_path, transcode
```

I also have similarly styled relative imports in `model.py` and `__main__.py`
All similar imports throw errors in both `pylint` (2.5.3) and `mypy` (0.761) when the tools are automatically run in my IDE (Code - OSS), e.g.:

```
Attempted relative import beyond top-level package pylint(relative-beyond-top-level) [13,1]
Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named '.model' mypy(error) [13,1]
Attempted relative import beyond top-level package pylint(relative-beyond-top-level) [14,1]
Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named '.tools' mypy(error) [14,1]
See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_mypy.html#missing-imports mypy(note) [13,1]
```

When I add a blank `__init__.py` file to the folder, the errors disappear.

**I don't need this `__init__.py` file for the package to work.**

I thought that post-PEP 420, it shouldn't be required, especially if it's just there to satisfy linters.

Is there something else I'm doing wrong, or should I just add the `__init__.py` and get over it :) ?

Config for `pylint` is in `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.pylint.'MESSAGES CONTROL']
# Pylint and black disagree on hanging indentation.
disable = "C0330"

[tool.pylint.MISCELLANEOUS]
# Note: By default, "TODO" is flagged, this is disabled by omitting it
#       from the list below.
notes = "FIXME,XXX"
```

Config for `mypy` is in `mypy.ini`:

```
[mypy]
disallow_untyped_calls = True
disallow_untyped_defs = True
disallow_incomplete_defs = True
disallow_untyped_decorators = True
mypy_path = src
namespace_packages = True

[mypy-openpyxl]
ignore_missing_imports = True

[mypy-pulp]
ignore_missing_imports = True

[mypy-pytest]
ignore_missing_imports = True
```

I'm running python 3.8.0.

Comment: Mind that PEP 420 doesn't say "you can create a package by omitting ``__init__.py``", it says "you create a *namespace* package by omitting an ``__init__.py``". So do you want a package or do you want a *namespace* package?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You make a good point, I don't explicitly want a namespace package - I was merely trying to cut down on file clutter. Perhaps best to add the `__init__.py` so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PEP 420 does not *allow* to "create a package by omitting `__init__.py`", it *enforces* to "create a *namespace* package by omitting `__init__.py`". This means:

- If you want a package, add `__init__.py`.
- If you want a *namespace* package, omit `__init__.py`.

While using a namespace package like a regular package usually works, it may unexpectedly fail when package names clash. In most cases, a namespace package is not desirable.

Comment: It "may unexpectedly fail when package names clash"? Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

For mypy, an alternative to the accepted answer is to use mypy option  `--namespace-packages` so that namespace packages are taken into account by mypy