# Can I avoid getting pylint errors from not having __init__.py without disabling rules?

Tags: python, python-import, pylint

This is my project

```
root
├── main.py
└── utils
    └── tool.py
```

This is my main

```
from utils.tool import some_func
```

It works but I'm getting `Pylint(E0611:no-name-in-module)`. I'm pretty new to Python so I don't want to break any rules. But is there any way to get rid of this message without disabling the rule or breaking commonly accepted conventions?

I'm asking because I dislike the idea of spraying `__init__.py` files into all of my project folders.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62831486/requirement-for-init-py-just-to-satisfy-pylint-and-mypy

Comment: As @mkrieger1 said, be careful, not putting in the `__init__.py` may or may not cause weird bugs depending on your use case.